# File Isn't Deleting

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I have a code that finds files that are less than 20 seconds old. It's finding them, but I can't get them deleted. I am using remove(). I've tried using remove with wildcards but no luck. It has to be something with the syntax. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
using namespace std; 
typedef vector<WIN32_FIND_DATA> tFoundFilesVector; 
std::wstring LastWriteTime;   
int getFileList(const char * filespec, tFoundFilesVector &foundFiles)
{ 
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData; 
    HANDLE h; 
    int validResult=true; 

    int numFoundFiles = 0; 
    h = FindFirstFile((LPCSTR)filespec, &findData); 
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        return 0; 

    while (validResult) 
    { 
        numFoundFiles++; 
        foundFiles.push_back(findData); 
        validResult = FindNextFile(h, &findData); 
    } 
    return numFoundFiles; 
} 

void showFileAge(tFoundFilesVector &fileList) 
{ 
    unsigned _int64 fileTime, curTime, age; 
    tFoundFilesVector::iterator iter; 
    FILETIME ftNow; 
    CoFileTimeNow(&ftNow); 
          curTime = ((_int64) ftNow.dwHighDateTime << 32) + ftNow.dwLowDateTime; 

          for (iter=fileList.begin(); iter<fileList.end(); iter++) 
   { 
        fileTime = ((_int64)iter->ftLastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime << 32) + iter- >ftLastWriteTime.dwLowDateTime; 

        age = curTime - fileTime;
    if (age <= (_int64)200000000UL)
    {
        wcout << " Delete: '" <<endl;
        wcout << "FILE: '" << iter->cFileName << "', AGE: " << (_int64)age/10000000UL << "  seconds" << endl; 
        remove("C:\\mapper\\iter->cFileName");

        }
        else
        {
        //wcout << " Quit: '" <<endl;
        //return;
    }
        } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    string fileSpec = "*.*"; 
    tFoundFilesVector foundFiles; 
    tFoundFilesVector::iterator iter; 

    int foundCount = 0; 

    getFileList("c:\\Mapper\\*.txt", foundFiles); 
    getFileList("c:\\Mapper\\*.jpg", foundFiles);
     foundCount = foundFiles.size(); 
    if (foundCount) 
    { 
        wcout << "Found "<<foundCount<<" matching files.\n"; 
        showFileAge(foundFiles); 
    } 
    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `remove("C:\\mapper\\iter->cFileName");`? That cannot possibly work. You should build the file's path from the two strings instead.

Comment: Thank you, How would I do this? I'm still very new!

Comment: Frédéric Hamidi is correct, C++ does not have "string interpolation", which is a feature mostly found in dynamic/scripting languages.

Comment: @Ben, yup, but that usually requires a special token (e.g. the `$` character) in order to determine the substrings that must be interpolated. The code in the question would fail even in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the strings "C:\mapper\" with whatever is in iter->cFileName. The most simple way of doing that would be to use the std::string class.
The result would look something like this:

```
remove(string("c:\\mapper\\").append(string(iter->cFileName)).c_str());
```

This assumes you do not use unicode encoding of your strings, otherwise you need to use std::wstring. To use these classes you will also need to include

```
#include <string>
```

in the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that it would be so involved to remove a file ! :) But I should know better by now. Help is greatly appreciated! Have a good day.